# How to make an array of my output separately to get only a section of my output

Tags: perl

I am getting output of my file using a foreach loop in an array.

How can I extract only  a section of my file in a new array after getting everything.

This is my code

```
foreach (@genetic_codes) {
  chomp;
  my @genetic_codes = split(':', $_);
  if (@genetic_codes != 5) { # error on this line next;
  }
  my $amino_acid = join('","', split(/,/, $genetic_codes[4]));
  print "$genetic_codes[2]=> [$genetic_codes[0],$genetic_codes[1],[$amino_acid]],\n";
}
```

This is my output which is correct.

```
"M"=> ["Methionine","Met",["ATG"]],
"F"=> ["Phenylalanine","Phe",["TTT"," TTC"]],
"P"=> ["Proline","Pro",["CCT"," CCC"," CCA"," CCG"]],
"S"=> ["Serine","Ser",["TCT"," TCC"," TCA"," TCG"," AGT"," AGC"]],
"T"=> ["Threonine","Thr",["ACT"," ACC"," ACA"," ACG"]],
"W"=> ["Tryptophan","Trp",["TGG"]],
```

Now I need to take all codons and put them into a variable `Z` getting rid of duplicates.

Do I need to make a foreach loop separately?

I am totally lost, please help.
I need my last output of ----

```
"Z"=>["ACT","AGT",---------------SO ON]],
```

ALL THE THREE LETTERS FROM ABOVE LINES IN ONE VARIABLE.

Comment: Can you elaborate what have you done and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: You need to be way more specific about what you are asking. If you have a file contained in an array (or rather, you have *an array*), you can access part of the array with a slice: `@array[2 .. 5]` (lines 3 to 6 in a file).

Comment: I am getting output of my file in the form of a hash.Now I need to make an array where I can get only one section of my hash.

Comment: "M"=> ["Methionine","Met",["ATG"]],
"F"=> ["Phenylalanine","Phe",["TTT"," TTC"]],
"P"=> ["Proline","Pro",["CCT"," CCC"," CCA"," CCG"]],
"S"=> ["Serine","Ser",["TCT"," TCC"," TCA"," TCG"," AGT"," AGC"]],
"T"=> ["Threonine","Thr",["ACT"," ACC"," ACA"," ACG"]],
"W"=> ["Tryptophan","Trp",["TGG"]],
This is my output which is correct now i need to take all codons only and put them in a variable Z getting rid of duplicates.

Comment: @priyanka Post the code that you have tried and the errors you get. Don't post code in comments, use the "edit" button below your question.

Comment: foreach(@genetic_codes){
    chomp;
    my @genetic_codes = split(':',$_);
    if(@genetic_codes != 5){
        # error on this line
        next;
    }    
    my $amino_acid = join('","',split(/,/,$genetic_codes[4]));
    
    
   
    
  print "$genetic_codes[2]=> [$genetic_codes[0],$genetic_codes[1],[$amino_acid]],\n";
  
   
}

Comment: @priyanka You should also be aware that if you say "codons", people might not understand what you mean.

Comment: Till now not getting any errors got desired output. But not sure about the second part.

Comment: three capital letters in my output....

Comment: Please stop posting information in comments. Edit your question to add it there as I have done and as TLP requested you to do. Also realize that your output is wrong, as your codons have leading spaces like `" CCC"`.

Comment: @priyanka You should perhaps consider storing the data in an actual hash instead of printing it. Then you could easily retrieve data such as `my @codons = @{$hash{"M"}{"codons"}}`

Comment: @TLP THANKS BUT IT DIDN'T WORK.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code so that the codons are stored in a separate array for each line of output. Then you can build up a hash from line to line.

I have also fixed the processing of the input so that your data is correct.

Since you haven't provided any sample input data I have fabricated something that I thin k is correct, and produces the output you show in your question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %codons;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @genetic_codes = split /:/;
  @genetic_codes == 5 or die "Invalid data found";
  my @amino_acids = $genetic_codes[4] =~ /[ACTG]+/g;
  printf "%s => [%s, %s, [%s]],\n",
      @genetic_codes[2, 0, 1],
      join ', ', map qq{"$_"}, @amino_acids;#
  $codons{$_}++ for @amino_acids;
}
printf qq{"%s" => [%s]\n}, 'Z', join ', ', map qq{"$_"}, sort keys %codons;

__DATA__
"Methionine":"Met":"M":"":"ATG"
"Phenylalanine":"Phe":"F":"":"TTT, TTC"
"Proline":"Pro":"P":"":"CCT, CCC, CCA, CCG"
"Serine":"Ser":"S":"":"TCT, TCC, TCA, TCG, AGT, AGC"
"Threonine":"Thr":"T":"":"ACT, ACC, ACA, ACG"
"Tryptophan":"Trp":"W":"":"TGG"
```

**output**

```
"M" => ["Methionine", "Met", ["ATG"]],
"F" => ["Phenylalanine", "Phe", ["TTT", "TTC"]],
"P" => ["Proline", "Pro", ["CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"]],
"S" => ["Serine", "Ser", ["TCT", "TCC", "TCA", "TCG", "AGT", "AGC"]],
"T" => ["Threonine", "Thr", ["ACT", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"]],
"W" => ["Tryptophan", "Trp", ["TGG"]],
"Z" => ["ACA", "ACC", "ACG", "ACT", "AGC", "AGT", "ATG", "CCA", "CCC", "CCG", "CCT", "TCA", "TCC", "TCG", "TCT", "TGG", "TTC", "TTT"]
```

Comment: you are a genius! this is exactly what I wanted for my output,I am not very sure whether I am getting rid of duplicates or not,please explain briefly...

Comment: Yes, duplicates are being removed by incrementing the corresponding element of the hash (`$codons{$_}++ for @amino_acids`) and then listing all the hash keys at the end.